# Como guardar el contenido de un QR (cedula de identidad o DNI) en una base de datos mysql

Tags: php, mysql, qr

Buen día a todos, si alguien me puede ayudar, necesito saber como guardar el contenido de un QR (cedula de identidad o DNI) en una base de datos mysql, gracias